# Get data from a controller, return as json and preview in cshtml

Tags: c#, json, razor, controller

I have a controller that I get result exampleController.cs:

```
public expChart{
...
   public ActionResult ByContainer(int id)
    {
        var elementIds = _systemSettings.Z3FromZBIds; // CritialWorkPermitIds; 

        var kpiElements = CacheService.AllVisibleElements
                                      .Where(x => elementIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

        var container = _kpiContainerService.Find(id);

        var result = _kpiTrendService.MonthByContainer(kpiElements, container);
        return AsJson(result);
    } 
}
```

I call it in example.cshtml:

```
<div class="panel" style="display: none;" id="bottom-area-trend-charts" ng-ontroller="exampleController">
    <div >
        TEST
        {{element.Name}}
    </div>

</div>
```

I think it is something wrong with my calling. How can I call the result in my controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you return the content in Json ? You want retrieve elements in  AJAX ?

Comment: yes, I need to retrieve it in AJAX

Comment: If you want to see the result, you can check it in a web browser : localhost/example/ByContainer/{yourid}

Comment: I can see the result and it is correct. I want to show it as a list in my cshtml page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/YourController/ByContainer",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { id: 10 }, // the value id for call your controller
            success: function (data) {
                // make sure your result variable is enumerable.
                $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                    $("#bottom-area-trend-charts div").append("<p>" + element.Name + "</p>");
                });
            },
            error: function (xqr, errorMessage) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And change your action to this:

```
public JsonResult ByContainer(int id)
{
    var elementIds = _systemSettings.Z3FromZBIds; // CritialWorkPermitIds; 

    var kpiElements = CacheService.AllVisibleElements
                                    .Where(x => elementIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

    var container = _kpiContainerService.Find(id);

    var result = _kpiTrendService.MonthByContainer(kpiElements, container);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```